# How to create image from a 2D array of 1's and 0's in javascript?

Tags: javascript, raster

I have a an 2d array of 1's and 0's and I'd like to create a black and white image from that array in my react application.

My array looks something like this but much bigger:

```
var items = [
  [0, 1, 1, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 1]
];
```

and I want to show something like:
[image]

How can I output a black and white raster plot from my array in my react application?

Comment: I'd draw on a `<canvas>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a library that renders PNGs or other image formats, but since you have a simple list of pixels, an SVG image is not hard to render out, either. *Technically* this isn't a raster plot, as it's a vector image but you can render it out at 4x3 pixels if you wanted to and it'll stay crisp.

```js
function drawSvg(tag, rows) {
  // If you're sure all rows are always the same size, it's 
  // faster and simpler to just do `rows[0].length`.
  const pixelWidth = rows.reduce((max, row) => Math.max(max, row.length), 0);
  const pixelHeight = rows.length;

  // The `viewBox` of a SVG tag is the viewport to draw to.
  // Since we want 1 "pixel" in our vector to be 1 pixel in the output,
  // the viewbox will be 0 -0.5 4 3 for our 4x3 sample image.
  // The -0.5 shift upwards is because of how SVG aligns things.
  tag.setAttribute('viewBox', `0 -0.5 ${pixelWidth} ${pixelHeight}`);
  // The width/height of a SVG tag can be overwritten by CSS to your liking,
  // but having them makes sure the image stays the correct aspect ratio.
  tag.setAttribute('width', pixelWidth);
  tag.setAttribute('height', pixelHeight);

  const path = tag.querySelector('path');
  
  let data = '';
  for (let line = 0; line < rows.length; line++) {
    // [M]ove absolutely to 0,Y
    data += ` M0,${line}`;
    const row = rows[line];
    for (const pixel of row) {
      if (pixel) {
        // Draw a [h]orizontal line, 1 unit wide.
        data += ` h1`;
      } else {
        // [m]ove relatively to +1,+0.
        data += ` m1,0`;
      }
    }
  }
  // Output will be something like 'M0,0 h1 m1,0 h1'.
  path.setAttribute('d', data);

  // You can also create a link to a SVG by embedding it as a data URL.
  // encodeURIComponent is smaller than Base64Encode.
  // You could minify the input, but we don't need to bother for the sample.
  const href = `data:image/svg+xml,${encodeURIComponent(tag.outerHTML)}`;
  
  // Create an <img src="">
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.classList.add('output');
  img.setAttribute('src', href);
  tag.parentNode.insertBefore(img, tag);

  // Works as a background image, too.
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('output');
  div.style.backgroundImage = `url("${href}")`;
  tag.parentNode.insertBefore(div, tag);
}

addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  drawSvg(document.querySelector('svg.output'), [
    [0, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1]
  ]);
});
```

```css
.output {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
img.output {
  border-color: lime;
}
div.output {
  background: no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 75px;
  border-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1 1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" class="output">
  <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M0" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two nested loops to iterate through each row and each item in a row. Then conditionally render elements (e. g. `<div>`) and style them accordingly. To give an idea where the prop `matrix` is your 2d array.

```
const Raster = ({matrix}) => {
  return (
    <>
      {matrix.forEach(row => {
        return (
          <div>
            {row.forEach(item => {
              return (
                <div
                  style={{
                    height: 50,
                    width: 50,
                    backgroundColor: 0 === item ? "white" : "black"
                  }}
                ></div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Is there any downside to writing a thousands of div's to the browser like this?

Comment: A downside could be performance. But not noticeable for small images or one big one. You are already creating an image from an array - that's already less performant than just having the image. Using classes instead of inline styles would be better.

Comment: You could theoretically always optimize everything but personally, I'd say usually this is just how it's done in React. If you wanna get fancy go for a canvas. It depends on your use case as well. But the performance changes are so insignificantly small here. We are talking about 12 divs to be percise.